# Using two "tool batteries" in parallel - Need a BMS?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, parallel, bms

I have built a Bluetooth speaker, which is currently powered by a single 18V "drill battery" (Bosch BAT609 battery, to be exact - each pack has 5 lithium ion cells, and I assume, its own BMS to manage the individual cells).

My question is - **Can I wire two of those in parallel to double the run time, without worry of damaging them?**

I'm asking as it has been said that if the two battery packs differ in any way in terms of prior usage, lifespan, etc. (which mine definitely do), then this may not be a good idea.

**Is there a proper approach to doing this (e.g. putting some kind of battery capacity balancer or other BMS component), or is it just a bad idea?**

There's no charging component so no worries there. They'll still be charged individually via their usual Bosch charger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The risk of doing this is pairing two ***unbalanced*** batteries together in parallel.

Consider this, if one nominal 18V battery is fully charged it would now be ~21V (lets call this *Battery A*), if the second battery is not fully charged, or worst case fully discharged it's voltage might sit around the ~15V mark (lets call this *Battery B*).

When two unbalanced batteries are connected, they will try to balance themselves out, as voltage is equal in parallel. As such, the fully charged battery will dump its energy into the less charged battery. Tied together only by a wire, the resistance is a few milliohms. So using ohms law:

```
V = I*R
I = V/R
I = Voltage of Battery / wire resistance + internal battery resistance + a few other factors
I = a large amount of current (could be 100s of Amps)
```

Now obviously it isn't safe to dump 100s of amps but you may be starting to see the point, when these batteries are unbalanced if you have nothing in between to stop the flow of current you will discharge an immense amount of energy in a finite time, which is a risk damage to your batteries and most *critically* a fire hazard.

So your follow up question will naturally be '*What if I fully charge them both?*", this is where the question of the battery age comes into play - if Battery B is vastly older that Battery A, it will not be able to hold the same amount of energy and thus discharge at different rates causing problems.

In summary, if you intend on doing this you need to know what you're doing, there **needs to be protection** such as a fuse to protect overcurrent situations, however this may already be internal to the Bosch battery, and even then it might still not be safe to do. Generally this isn't recommended.